# JavaScript dynamically add a canvas tag into HTML file failed

Tags: javascript, canvas

I want to use separate javascript file to dynamically add a  tag into a HTML file, but always get an error: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined. Really confused. Can anyone help ? Thank you so much! Below is my code in a .js file:

```
var canvasGraphic = (function(){
    return {
        getCanvas:function(){
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
            body.appendChild(canvas);
            canvas.style.border = "black solid";
        }
    }
})();

canvasGraphic.getCanvas();
```

Comment: Can you try debugging by setting your browser debugger to pause on all exceptions?  This snippet runs in a Stack Overflow snippet.  Where are you putting your `<script src="..."></script>`?  Before or after `<body>`?

Comment: Yeah, if I run this code in the same HTML file, after add a <script> tag, that's fine, but move to a .js file, it throws this error

Comment: Add the HTML file to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does this code exist in the lifecycle of the page? Are you certain that the document has loaded and is ready before getCanvas() is called?

Let's use this example index.html document. It will display your error:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var canvasGraphic = (function(){
    return {
        getCanvas:function(){
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
            body.appendChild(canvas);
            canvas.style.border = "black solid";
        }
    }
})();

canvasGraphic.getCanvas();
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<html>
```

However if we put the call to getCanvas() inside another function and call that function onload of the body, the error disappears:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var canvasGraphic = (function(){
    return {
        getCanvas:function(){
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
            body.appendChild(canvas);
            canvas.style.border = "black solid";
        }
    }
})();

function initialize() {
    canvasGraphic.getCanvas();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize();">
</body>
<html>
```

There are many ways to get this accomplished, this one was easy. The key is to be sure that your documents DOM has finished loading before calling your function.

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

The message you are getting means that `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]` has returned `undefined`. (That's why the error message says `appendChild` does not exist as a method of `body`.)

**Is your code running before the document has loaded?**

In that case, you might not be able to find the `body` element. If you can move your script element to the bottom of the `body` tag, do that instead (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41150862/7256039) first by [A.J.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2720743/a-j)).

```
<body>
    <main>All your content, tags, whatever...</main>
    <script src="your-code.js"></script>
</body>
```

Otherwise, you might need to attach an event handler to the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

Also, note that `document.body` will get the body tag of a document.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var canvasGraphic = (function() {
    return {
      getCanvas: function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        canvas.style.border = "black solid";
        return canvas;
      }
    }
  })();

  canvasGraphic.getCanvas();
})
```

**An aside:** you probably wanted to `return canvas` from your `getCanvas` function

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be nothing wrong with your code. Just load your script file at the end of the body tag, or execute the code after the DOM's readyState is ready.

```js
var canvasGraphic = (function() {
  return {
    getCanvas: function() {
      var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
      body.appendChild(canvas);
      canvas.style.border = "black solid";
    }
  }
})();

canvasGraphic.getCanvas();
```

Answer (score 0):

The code runs well on a JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vazu4wj5/

The only change I would suggest is to change `body.appendChild(canvas);` to `document.body.appendChild(canvas);`, it's just more specific.

Here's the final code:

```
var canvasGraphic = (function(){
    return {
        getCanvas:function(){
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            canvas.style.border = "black solid";
        }
    }
})();

canvasGraphic.getCanvas();
```

Comment: In that case, you don't really need `var body = document.getElementsByTagName(...` anymore.